# Gnuplot: set fixed width for color box

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot to plot some matrix files as heatmaps. These matrixes can be horizontal (height of matrix is lower than its width) or vertical (height of matrix is higher than its width).

Everything is working fine - except the color box. I Have set `set size ratio -1` to get a heatmap with quadrats that have an aspect ration of 1:1. This command stretches or shrinks the graph. But it also stretches or shrinks the color box.

***I would like to have a fixed width for my color box*** because some of my matrix files have got a very small width - this results in a very thin color box. I have tried to set the width of my colorbox manually. But this isn't possible without setting its origin and complete size manually, too.

**Examples**

Horizontal:

```
unset key
set cbrange [0:5]
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:5]
set size ratio -1
set cbtics out nomirror
$map1 << EOD
5 4 3 1 0 5 4 3 1 0
2 2 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 2 3 0 0 0 2 3
0 1 2 4 3 2 2 0 0 1
EOD
plot '$map1' using ($1+.5):($2+.5):($3) matrix with image
```

[image]

Vertical:

```
unset key
set cbrange [0:5]
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:10]
set size ratio -1
set cbtics out nomirror
$map1 << EOD
5 4 3 1 0
2 2 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 2 3
0 1 2 4 3
5 4 3 1 0
2 2 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 2 3
2 2 0 0 1
EOD
plot '$map1' using ($1+.5):($2+.5):($3) matrix with image
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to specify both origin and entire size? For example, `set colorbox user origin graph 1.1, first 0 size first 1, graph 1` makes a colorbox that is as wide as one of your pixels, and as high as the entire graph. You might have to set the right margin to make a little room for the colorbar in this case.

Comment: Thank you @user8153! You helped me very much!I decided to use `set colorbox user origin graph 1, graph 0 size cbwidth, graph 1` in combination with `set rmargin at screen 0.875`. `cbwith` is variable with a static width. Tomorrow I will give a full answer with all details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user8153 offered a nice solution for my problem. It works like a charm for my given examples. But I had to change his commands a little bit. Otherwise it wouldn't work with my real input data:

```
# [...]
cbwidth = 0.034
rightmargin = 0.875
set colorbox user origin graph 1, graph 0 size cbwidth, graph 1
set rmargin at screen rightmargin
# [...]
```

This will plot a graph with a colorbox next to it (without any space between the graphs window and the color box - we will fix that later). The colorboxs width is 3.4% of the output width (when using a term like png or pngcairo, svg or eps and so on...).

I prefer a little bit space between the graph and colorbox. The origin (position) of my colorbox is `graph 1, graph 0`. This position is equal to the lower right handcorner of the graphs window. **1** means **100%** of this window. So if we like to add some extra space we just have to increase this percentage. @user8153 decided to add 10% extra space = `origin graph 1.1, graph 0` (have a look at his comment - I changed `first 0` to `graph 0`). Unfortunality we can not set a static percentage in this case because this 100% refers to the graphs window (not to the canvas width - respectively the  hole plot image) and the width of the graphs window changes with the matrixes aspect ratio. So you have to adjust this value everytime depending on the real width of the graphs window.

To get this done automatically I would suggest to set the size of the terminal manually to a higher value than 640x480 (in this case 1200x1200, crop will cut white space):

```
set term pngcairo size 1200,1200 crop
```

After that you are free to calculate the x-position of your colorbox. Either use gnuplots *if/else* or use another language (in my case it's typescript because I am calling gnuplot through a node.js-gnuplot-wrapper - but the logic is the same):

```
const size = 1200             // canvas size (width and height): 1200px 
const cbspace = 0.017;        // prefered space between colorbox and window: 20px / 1200px
const rmargin = 0.875;        // right margin next to the graphs window 
let graphWindowWidth: number; // real width of the graphs window

if (matrixHeight > matrixWidth) {
    graphWindowWidth = (matrixWidth / matrixHeight) * size;
} else {
    graphWindowWidth = size * rmargin;
}
let cbPosX = (cbspace * size + graphWidth) / graphWidth;
```

Of course you shouldn't forget that xtics and ytics, labels for x- and y-axis and the title need some space to. These are not included in the upper algorithm. Maybe somebody has got a better solution about how to get the real graphs window width. Once you got that value you can modify the origin command part of the colorbox:

from: `set colorbox user origin graph 1, graph 0 size cbwidth, graph 1`

to: `set colorbox user origin graph cbPosX, graph 0 size cbwidth, graph 1`